# Variadic arguments bug Macbook Air M1

Tags: printf, variadic-functions, apple-m1

I'm currently creating a printf function from scratch which is working on a iMac 2020 and not on Air M1

If I try to test with the same % and different results, it will always show the first one.

For example:
ft_printf(“test %s %s”, “test2", “test3”)
Output:
test test2 test2

But the output on the iMac is the correct one:
test test2 test3

this is the main function:

```
int main()
{
    ft_printf("test %s %s\n", "test2", "test3");
    printf("test %s %s\n", "test2", "test3");
    return (0);
}

int ft_printf(const char *str, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int     cont;
    int     ret;

    cont = 0;
    va_start(ap, str);
    while (str[cont] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[cont] == '%')
        {
            ft_after_percentage(ap, str[cont + 1]);
            cont += 2;
            continue ;
        }
        write(1, &str[cont], 1);
        ft_count_return(0);
        cont++;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    ret = ft_count_return(0) - 1;
    ft_count_return(1);
    return (ret);
}

void    ft_after_percentage(va_list ap, char c)
{
    if (c == 'c')
        ft_putchar(va_arg(ap, int));
    else if (c == 's')
        ft_putstr(va_arg(ap, char *));
    else if (c == 'p')
        ft_percentage_p(va_arg(ap, long unsigned));
    else if (c == 'd')
        ft_putnbr(va_arg(ap, int));
    else if (c == 'i')
        ft_putnbr(va_arg(ap, int));
    else if (c == 'u')
        ft_uns_putnbr(va_arg(ap, unsigned int));
    else if (c == 'x')
        ft_puthex(va_arg(ap, int), "0123456789abcdef");
    else if (c == 'X')
        ft_puthex(va_arg(ap, int), "0123456789ABCDEF");
    else if (c == '%')
        ft_putchar('%');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have passed the `va_list` variable by value to another function which uses `va_arg()` on it, you are not supposed to use that `va_list` variable in the calling function again.

The C99 standard, in the section for the stdarg.h header, says:

> The type declared is `va_list` which is an object type suitable for
> holding information needed by the macros `va_start`, `va_arg`,
> `va_end`, and `va_copy`. If access to the varying arguments is
> desired, the called function shall declare an object (generally
> referred to as `ap` in this subclause) having type `va_list`. **The
> object `ap` may be passed as an argument to another function; if that
> function invokes the `va_arg` macro with parameter `ap`, the value of
> `ap` in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to
> the `va_end` macro prior to any further reference to
> `ap`.**<sup>212)</sup>

So here, you pass `ap` by value to `ft_after_percentage()`, which calls `va_arg()` on it, and then you continue to use `ap` in the calling function (by passing it to `ft_after_percentage()` for the second variable argument). This causes undefined behavior. It might happen to work on one architecture, but not another, due to differences in how `va_list` is implemented between architectures.

The footnote from above suggests for your `ft_after_percentage()` to instead take a `va_list *`, and pass `&ap` to it:

> : 212) It is permitted to create a pointer to a `va_list` and pass that
> pointer to another function, in which case the original function may
> make further use of the original list after the other function
> returns.